# React - TypeError: baseReducer is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

im making a SPA using React. I want the states persits after page refresh so i used 'redux-persist'. I dont know if my import 'allReducers' is wrong because the message i recived is  **TypeError: baseReducer is not a function**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import allReducers from './redux/store'
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";


const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers);
let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
let persistor = persistStore(store);


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                        <App />
                    </PersistGate>
                </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

but finally when the page is rendered i got this message **TypeError: baseReducer is not a function**

**This is ./redux/store**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TO_CART, GET_COURSE_LIST, USUARIO_LOGIN } from './action'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'



const initialCart = {
    cart:[]
}

const initialCourses ={
    courses:[]
}

const initialUser ={
    user:{}
}

const cartReducer = ( state = initialCart,action) => {
    console.log(action)

    if(action.type===ADD_TO_CART)
    {

        if(state.cart.find(c=>c===action.id)) 
        {
            return state
        }

        return{
            ...state,
            cart: state.cart.concat(action.id),            
        }

    }
    return state

}

const coursesReducer = (state=initialCourses, action) =>{
    console.log(action)
    if(action.type === GET_COURSE_LIST){
        return {
            ...state,
            courses: action.courses
        }
    }
    return state
}

const userReducer = (state=initialUser, action)=>{
    console.log(action)
    if(action.type === USER_LOGIN){
        return {
            ...state,
            user: action.user
        }
    }
    return state

}

const storage = createStore(combineReducers({cartReducer, coursesReducer, userReducer}), composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

export default storage
```

Comment: Could you please show the exports from `./redux/store` or `./redux/store/index`, whichever you're using? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60747898/edit) your question to include details.

Comment: look i added my ./redux/store

Answer (score 8):

The `persistReducer` function expects a reducer, not a store.

You could export your reducer from the store file separately, or just export it as default if you're only using the persisted store. Here's an example of exporting it separately:

`./redux/store`:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({cartReducer, coursesReducer, userReducer})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
export default store
```

Your root component file:

```
import { rootReducer } from './redux/store'

// ...

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: this solution runs without an exception but after refresh page the states dont persist

Comment: Take a look at your Redux devtools. Do you see the state changing? Do you see the state being initialized? Also look at the Application tab (Chrome) or Storage tab (Firefox) in your browser's Developer Tools. Do you see anything there in the LocalStorage tab?

Comment: I made that change you said , when i change a state i see that change at Redux devtools and runs well but when refresh the page the state don't persist :S

Comment: Do you see anything in LocalStorage?

Comment: where i can see the LocalStorage?

Comment: See my previous comment. You might want to open a new quesrion with the new code that doesn't crash.

Comment: i see the LocalStorage at the Application tab (Chrome) and i can see the arrays of initialCart, initialCourses, initialUsers emptys but when i change the states at the pages those arrays that i can see at the LocalStorage stills empty

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that I was using store.dispatch() in a functional component instead of a direct dispatch() from useDispatch.

Watch out.

Comment: i had same issue, and it fix only if i remove not only store.dispatch(), also i removed import line and the errors gone 
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to wrap my `rootReducer` with `combineReducers`

Before:

```
const rootReducer = {
// my reducers
}
```

After:

```
const rootReducer = combinedReducers({
// my reducers
})
```